# TeXstudio shortcuts for next/previous placeholder not working on Mac

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

I'm on a Mac and trying to make a shortcuts on TexStudio (latest version) for next/previous placeholder, but nothing is working. On mac there seems to be no default shortcut for these, so I'm trying to set some up.

I tried ctrl+left/right arrow, but this is not an allowed combination on TeXstudio (for Mac). I tried cmd+option+left/right arrow (and changed the shortcut that this was already assigned to), but this also does nothing. I even tried the complicated expression shift+option+cmd+left/right arrow, but this also does nothing.

Why do literally none of my shortcuts work, I presume the last one is not assigned to something already since it is so complicated?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up in `Preference/Shortcuts`.

[image]

, which works well in `Monterey`.